# jQuery & Prototype Conflict (Javascript Debugging)

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototypejs

We have a Magento store setup which seems to have an existing jQuery & Prototype conflict going on. When you access [our URL here](http://store.tintworld.com/custom-wheels-performance-tires/custom-wheels.html#/custom-wheels-performance-tires/custom-wheels.html?wheel_diameter=3635), it'll take a few moments and then load a single product (a wheel). If you click onto the image, it is intended that it'd bring up a lightbox but it just opens the image in the tab due to this conflict. I can even see an error is going into the console log, but don't know how to pause it so that I can see the error (it's too quick).

If I don't have an attribute checked off on the left, the image lightbox works fine. I know the image lightbox is powered by jQuery, and the layered navigation by Prototype. This is my reason for believing it's an issue with that. :-)

Comment: [jQuery has a special function to prevent conflict with libraries such as prototype](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript code, add a line like this to run jQuery in no-conflict mode:

```
var $jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Then, wherever you use jQuery, instead of using the default "$" symbol in a selector, use "$jQ" instead: for example,

```
$jQ([jQuery selector]).[jQuery function]();
```